# Cheezy page objects getting the page URL?

Tags: ruby, url, cucumber, pageobjects

I'm trying to return the current page object URL but I'm not sure how to do this.

My code looks like this:

```
class APage
include PageObject

page_url '/page_url.com'

def get_page_url
    return @page_url
end
```

But this doesn't work, as the `@page_url` does not exist. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A method was added for this in version 1.0 of the page-object gem (see Issue 217).

The method is called `page_url_value`. It would be used like:

```
page = APage.new(browser)
page.page_url_value
#=> "/page_url.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. `@page_url = 'page_url.com'`

Comment: Yes, I know I can create a variable with the same data, but what I meant was to get the value of the page_url attribute from the page object. Is there a way to do this? :)